# It is possible that users registering customers to sell

Tags: attributes, customer-account

I am creating an online store with Magento, but I wonder if it is possible to create an online store where users who register on the main page can create product catalogs and sell, as well as on ebay.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Magento is not designed for this and you will have to code this by yourself or buy a dropship extension. 
There is a paid extensions for this from Unirgy i can recommend, Unirgy_Dropship.